# PHP compare date_diff to lapse of time

Tags: php, date

If I have

```
$time_interval = date_diff(date1, date2)
```

How can I do this in PHP?

```
If ($time_interval >= ('2 months and 15 days'))
    echo "time is '2 months and 15 days' or more"
else
    echo "time is less than '2 months and 15 days'"
```

I tried

```
if ($time_interval->m <= 2 and $time_interval->d < 15)
```

But this will return `FALSE` for `1 month and 20 days` which is obviously wrong

Is there something like..?

```
$time_lapse = create_my_own_time_lapse(2months & 15 days)
```

Then it would be very neat to compare both

```
If ($time_interval >= $time_lapse)
```

**SOLUTION**

`date_diff` retuns a `DateInterval` object. I found the way to create my own `DateInterval` for '2 months and 15 days'. This is my updated code:

Visit [PHP DateInterval manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) for details

```
$today = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$another_day = new DateTime("2019-05-10");

$time_diff = date_diff($today, $another_day);

// 'P2M15D' is the interval_spec for '2 months and 15 days'
$time_interval = new DateInterval('P2M15D');

// Let's see our objects
print_r($time_diff);
print_r($timeInterval);

if($time_diff >= $time_interval)
    echo "<br/>time is '2 months and 15 days' or more";
else
    echo "<br/>time is less than '2 months and 15 days'";
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/1213708) answer, which means you can `echo $time_interval->days;`, BUT if you want 2 months - which depends how many days in each month this may not be as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is almost correct. Just remove the `and` and add `strtotime()`

from:

```
if ($time_interval >= ('2 months and 15 days'))
    echo "time is '2 months and 15 days' or more";
else
    echo "time is less than '2 months and 15 days'";
```

to:

```
if ($time_interval->getTimestamp()) >= strtotime('2 months 15 days'))
    echo "time is '2 months and 15 days' or more";
else
    echo "time is less than '2 months and 15 days'";
```

Comment: `strtotime($time_interval)` returns error `strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` because `$time_interval` is a **DateInterval** object

Comment: My bad, can you replace the `strtotime($time_interval)` to `$time_interval->getTimestamp()`

Comment: I think it is much better to work with `DateInterval` as I explain at the end of the question in the solution I found because `DateInterval` takes in count months with 30 or 31 days also february with 28/29 days. Anyways your answer works fine. ThankYou

Comment: TBH, not that much knowledge about classes like DateInterval, but thanks for accepting the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way of doing this is converting your time to seconds and than compare these seconds with amount of seconds equal to 2 months and 15 days.

```
$timeInterval = strtotime('2009-12-01') - strtotime('2009-10-01');
$overSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 75; // 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 75 days

if($timeInterval >= $overSeconds)
    echo "time is '2 months and 15 days' or more";
else
    echo "time is less than '2 months and 15 days'";
```

Comment: `if($timeInterval >= $overSeconds)` returns error: `Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int`

Comment: Just replace dates with your date. As easy as that. Replace 2009-12-01 and 2009-10-01 with dates you want to compare. You are putting objects there instead of actual string with dates.

Comment: I know, but in my real project code `$timeInterval` comes from `date_diff`I need to work with **DateTime Object**